# Cat hissing at kitten after rough night

Tags: cats, fear

I have 2 cats, Al (age 9) and our new rescue, Tom (12 weeks). When we first brought her home Tom and Al were surprisingly close. They played often, he would follow her around and call for her when he couldn’t see her and they slept together. However, a couple mornings ago Al was uncharacteristically tense. He was growling and hissing whenever he saw Tom and I found tufts of his hair by the window. I’m guessing she was playing too rough with him and he’d had enough. He has no injuries (neither does she) and to ease his anxiety we separated them for a bit, but now every time she comes back out he growls and hisses at her. It’s important to note that he doesn’t swat or lunge at her, but seems more stressed and afraid. We’ve back tracked on their time spent together, feeding them close but separated, giving them treats when they are together and my partner will play with her on one side of the room while I play and pet him on the other side. He seems fine when she is out of his sight in the same space but starts up again with his growling and hissing when she’s in his line of sight. We continue to do this with multiple breaks and while it is seeming to help a little (he is calming down faster and faster as soon as she leaves with every break) I’m not sure if it will help them be friends again in the long run. If anyone has any advice I would love to hear from you!